# API Key and security

Tags: android, security, api

Recently, I was watching a video from google I/O 2011. In part of that session, speaker pointed out that developers should keep API keys (such as google place and etc) in their own server side rather than client side and avoid direct connection. sounds pretty secure but for doing such thing developers need their own server side and web service as well which is not possible sometimes. Now, I wounder is their any secure approach to use API key in the client application(maybe encryption)?

Comment: Why is it not possible to run your own proxy-service? You can get a small VPS for $20/mo.

Comment: There is no doubt that using proxy or web service is the best and right way to do it. it gives the power to developer to govern or track its application but some developers don't follow this approach for several reasons and I bet there are hundreds app out there that didn't follow this right way

Comment: 20$ a month is not that much, but if you consider the ways you can monetize apps on android, there are chances that almost no one can afford such a service at this cost and hope to be rentable...

Comment: Do you the link to that google IO conference ?

Comment: to be honest I can't remember which one the session that was but I think in this session [link](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/best-practices-for-accessing-google-apis-on-android.html) the guy mentioned it

Comment: That guy was wrong. It doesn't really make a difference, because then people can just connect to your server to impersonate you with your key. As long as your app can connect to a server, so can anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the API, I suppose. Most APIs I've worked with are utilizing calls from the application webserver to the API server. So in that case the client never can see the key; it's only the returned content they see.

On the other hand, if it really is a client to API call, there is really no point in encrypting they key, because it has to be decrypted before the call can be made anyway. And in that case the user could easily spoof it.

Comment: I see your point, but some APIs give you the key that you need to post that when you want make request from the server (such as google place), and if you don't want use your own service to handle the request between client app and main server (which is not a good approach) you have to store that key somewhere in your app. however I don't think that accessing to your key by hackers(!) could be major a issue comparing to reliability of app (in case that key is changed) but still can consider about it.